# T-SQL Converting 28 Jan 2010 to Friday January 28, 2010

Tags: sql, t-sql

How do I convert this 2011-01-28 16:25:00.000 to this Friday, January 28,2010
Basically, my main question is how to I get a day from a number that represents the day in a month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select datename(dw, '2011-01-28 16:25:00.000')`

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @d datetime
set @d = '2011-01-28 16:25:00.000'

select DATENAME(DW, @d) + ', ' 
       + DATENAME(M, @d) + ' ' 
       + CAST(DATEPART(DD, @d) as CHAR(2)) + ', ' 
       + CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, @d) as CHAR(4))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know DateName function existed.

Comment: @user475337: The up arrow and the hollow check mark next to an answer are both excellent ways to say "thank you." :-)